# angularjs value vs factory

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularjs. I am trying to find out when to use value vs factory as a service. Here is my simple code from egghead.io tutorial:

```
.value('Data', function(){
    return {message:"I am data from a service"};
  })
```

The Data.message is bound to an input field. When I start the page, there is nothing in the input fields. If I change value to factory, the default message appears in the input field.

Here is the contoller:

```
controller('FirstCtrl', ['$scope','Data',function($scope, Data) {
    $scope.data = Data;
    console.log('exiting first controller');
  }])
```

and the index file:

```
<div ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
   <input type="text" ng-model="data.message">
   <h1>{{data.message}}</h1>
</div>
```

Why is the page blank when using value? My assumption is that value is not calculated or computed when the app starts whereas factory is?

Also, where can I find some documentation on $provide? Thank you all.

Comment: A little bit unrelated bit this helped me in a similar situation. factory vs. service vs. provide https://gist.github.com/Mithrandir0x/3639232.

To raise the chances to get a better answer it would be helpfull if you could provide an example via jsFiddle or a similar service.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Set the value to an object, rather than a function:

```
app.value('Data', {message:"I am data from a service"});
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WMGANf?p=preview)

See also [provide.value()](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/object/$provide#value), and this [video about $provide](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VxuN6WO3tIA&t=10m30s) (value, constant, service, factory, decorator, provider)

Comment: Thank you very much for the video. Clarified a lot.

Answer (score -1):

You should declare the controller as

```
   app.controller('DataController', ['Data', function DataController(Data){
      this.data = Data;
   }]);
```

and then use it in your page like in my code

```
<div ng-controller='DataController as dataController'>
      {{dataController.data()}}
   </div>
```